# Entity interceptors in Azure.Data.Tables

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

In the new SDK package - [Azure.Data.Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme-pre), how can you intercept the calls done to table storage / cosmos.
In the previous package (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage) it could be done through the method IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext) or ReadEntity. But now it seems that no interceptor is available.
Those were handy when we saved nullable types to Storage - for example int? or Guid?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure.Data.Tables has no interceptor concept, however it also allows you to define entities with properties of type `int?` or `Guid?`. When adding an entity to the table, any null properties are omitted from the entity.

Comment: I noticed that, thank you Christopher for the answer. However, using the previous Package we defined an interceptor that will write Int.Null in a string column to allow null for that record. In order to migrate, we have to support fetching those rows as well. The best I could think of is to override TablesTypeBinder, but that would mean working with local versions of nuget packages..

Comment: Just curious, why do you write string values to indicate null when the model will deserialize the absent column value as null naturally?

Comment: In the new package, yes. But we used the old package - WindowsAzure.Storage where it was not the case.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I thought you meant that you'd still need to do that with the new package.